# Javascript - Download fileName diferente do original (quero igual)

Tags: php, javascript

Boa tarde Senhores, tudo bem?
Eu tenho um arquivo que eu gero em .XLS no php e peço para que faça download em javascript, ou seja, gero o aquivo em php e ele salva o arquivo na pasta e retorno o nome desse arquivo para o javascript e ele só faz o download.

Esta funcionando, faz o download certinho, porém, o nome do arquivo quando é salvo na pasta está: relatorio.xls

Quando eu baixo no javascript ele fica: _ __    _  __    _relatorio.xls

aparecem esses caracteres antes do nome. Eu já coloquei TRIM em todo lugar, porque não sei se isso pode ser causado por espaço, mas não resolveu.

meu javascript ta assim.

```
$.post({
            url: "handle.php", // the resource where youre request will go throw
            type: "POST", // HTTP verb
            data: {action: 'baixar_relatorio', tipo: $('#tipo').val(), status: $('#status').val(), carregamento: $('#carregamento').val(),
                datade: $('#datade').val(), dataate: $('#dataate').val(), placa: $('#placa').val(), motorista: $('#motorista').val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(response.trim()));
                a.href ='<?php echo  $_SESSION['URL'] ?>'+'/file/relatorio/logistic/'+response.trim();
                a.download = response;
                document.body.append(a);
                a.click();
                a.remove();

            }
        });
```

Ta baixando certinho, só o nome que ta esquisito, cheio de coisa antes. Na pasta da onde o arquivo é feito download, está com o nome certo.

Desde já agradeço a vocês pela atenção.

EDITADO: meu back-end duvido que seja, pq comigo já disse, o arquivo salva com o nome certo.... ta ai

```
<?php
```

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pdo/pdo-sqlserver.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPmailer/src/SMTP.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPmailer/src/Exception.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPmailer/src/OAuth.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/serasa/consulta_serasa.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cdc/consulta_cdc.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/script/mail.php';

session_start();

// BAIXAR EXCEL PHP

if ($_POST['action'] == 'baixar_relatorio') {

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once $_SESSION['ROOT'].'/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
require_once $_SESSION['ROOT'].'/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Cell.php';
require_once $_SESSION['ROOT'].'/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php';
require_once $_SESSION['ROOT'].'/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Style.php';

```
$file_name = 'relatorio-'.date('Y-m-d_His').'.xls';

$Conexao = ConexaoSQLServer_Quality::getConnection();

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
//$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$sharedStyle1 = new PHPExcel_Style();
$sharedStyle3 = new PHPExcel_Style();
$sharedStyle4 = new PHPExcel_Style();
$sharedStyle5 = new PHPExcel_Style();
$sharedStyle6 = new PHPExcel_Style();

$sharedStyle1->applyFromArray(
array('fill' => array(
            'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => '245c7b') // azul escuro
            ),
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'ffffff')
            )
    ));

$sharedStyle3->applyFromArray(
array('fill' => array(
            'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'e9f2fc') // azul claro
            ),
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true,
            ),
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT,
         )
));

$sharedStyle4->applyFromArray(
array('fill' => array(
            'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'fff7e6') // rosa claro
            ),
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true,
            ),
         'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT,
         )
));



$sharedStyle5->applyFromArray(
array('fill' => array(
            'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => '78afed') // azul escuro
            ),
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'ffffff'),
            ),
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT,
         )
));

$sharedStyle6->applyFromArray(
array('fill' => array(
            'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'ffcc66') // rosa escuro
            ),
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'ffffff'),
        ),
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT,
        )
));


    $array_status_pai = array(
        'A' => 'Aguardando',
        'Z' => 'Finalizado',
        'O' => 'Ordem Aceita',
        'B' => 'Em Andamento',
        'F' => 'Cancelado',
    );

    $array_status_filho = array(
        'A' => 'Chegou ao patio',
        'B' => 'Entrada',
        'G' => 'Aguardando OP',
        'C' => 'Carga Autorizada',
        'D' => 'Saida',
        'Z' => 'Finalizado',
    );


    $where = null;
    if($_POST['datade'] != null and $_POST['dataate'] != null){
            $d1 = substr($_POST['datade'], 0, 2);
            $m1 = substr($_POST['datade'], 3, 2);
            $a1 = substr($_POST['datade'], 6, 4);
            $data1 = $a1.'-'.$m1.'-'.$d1;

            $d2 = substr($_POST['dataate'], 0, 2);
            $m2 = substr($_POST['dataate'], 3, 2);
            $a2 = substr($_POST['dataate'], 6, 4);
            $data2 = $a2.'-'.$m2.'-'.$d2;
        ($where == null) ? $where .= " WHERE O_DATA_CRIACAO BETWEEN '".$data1."' AND '".$data2."' " : $where .= " AND O_DATA_CRIACAO BETWEEN '".$data1."' AND '".$data2."' ";

    }else if($_POST['datade'] != null and $_POST['dataate'] == null){
        $d1 = substr($_POST['datade'], 0, 2);
        $m1 = substr($_POST['datade'], 3, 2);
        $a1 = substr($_POST['datade'], 6, 4);
        $data1 = $a1.'-'.$m1.'-'.$d1;

        ($where == null) ? $where .= " WHERE O_DATA_CRIACAO >= '".$data1."' " : $where .= " AND O_DATA_CRIACAO >= '".$data1."' ";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['status']) and $_POST['status'] != null){
        $w = null;
        if(!in_array("1", $_POST['status'])){
            foreach($_POST['status'] as $s){
                $w .= "'".$s."',";
            }
            ($where == null) ? $where .= " WHERE O_STATUS IN (".substr($w, 0, -1).") " : $where .= " AND O_STATUS IN (".substr($w, 0, -1).") ";
        }
    }
if($_POST['tipo'] == 2){

        if(isset($_POST['motorista']) and $_POST['motorista'] != null){
            $w = null;
            foreach($_POST['motorista'] as $m){
                $w .= "'".$m."',";
            }
            ($where == null) ? $where .= " WHERE OCT_MOTORISTA_CPF IN (".substr($w, 0, -1).") " : $where .= " AND OCT_MOTORISTA_CPF IN (".substr($w, 0, -1).") ";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['placa']) and $_POST['placa'] != null){
            ($where == null) ? $where .= " WHERE OCT_PLACA_CAVALO = '".$_POST['placa']."' " : $where .= " AND OCT_PLACA_CAVALO = '".$_POST['placa']."' ";
        }

    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setTitle('OutBound');
    // cabeçalho da planilha
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Outbound.')
            ->setCellValue('A2', 'ID')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'Pedido Protheus')
            ->setCellValue('C2', 'Pedido Cliente')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'Cliente')
            ->setCellValue('E2', 'Total Programado')
            ->setCellValue('F2', 'Solicitação')
            ->setCellValue('G2', 'Produção')
            ->setCellValue('H2', 'Entrega')
            ->setCellValue('I2', 'Previsão')
            ->setCellValue('J2', 'Status da OC')
            ->setCellValue('K2', 'Transportadora')
            ->setCellValue('L2', 'Motorista')
            ->setCellValue('M2', 'Volume')
            ->setCellValue('N2', 'Placa Cavalo')
            ->setCellValue('O2', 'Placa Carreta')
            ->setCellValue('P2', 'Status')
            ->setCellValue('Q2', 'Chegada')
            ->setCellValue('R2', 'Entrada')
            ->setCellValue('S2', 'Carregamento')
            ->setCellValue('T2', 'Saida')
            ->setCellValue('U2', 'Cancelado');


    // retornar produto acabado
    $array_out = array();
    $array_in = array();
    $linha = 2;

    $query = $Conexao->query("SELECT O_ID, O_TIPO, O_PEDIDO_PRO, O_PEDIDO_CLI, O_CLIENTE, O_TELEFONE, 
        convert(varchar, O_DATA_SOLICITA, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, O_DATA_SOLICITA, 8) O_DATA_SOLICITA, 
        convert(varchar, O_DATA_PROD, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, O_DATA_PROD, 8) O_DATA_PROD, 
        convert(varchar, O_DATA_ENTREGA, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, O_DATA_ENTREGA, 8) O_DATA_ENTREGA, 
        convert(varchar, O_DATA_PREVISAO, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, O_DATA_PREVISAO, 8) O_DATA_PREVISAO, 
        O_COD_PROD, O_FORMULA, O_TOTAL_PROG, O_SALDO, O_UNIDADE, O_CIDADE, O_SOLICITANTE, O_URGENCIA, O_GRUPO_CLI, O_OBS, 
        O_DETALHES, O_LOCAL_COLETA, O_STATUS, O_TRANSPORTADORA, OCT_ID, OCT_VOLUME, OCT_PLACA_CAVALO, OCT_PLACA_CARRETA, OCT_MOTORISTA_CPF, 
        OCT_MOTORISTA_NOME, 
        convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_CHEGADA, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_CHEGADA, 8) OCT_DATA_CHEGADA, OCT_TELEFONE_MOT, OCT_STATUS, 
        convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_ENTRADA, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_ENTRADA, 8) OCT_DATA_ENTRADA, 
        convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_CARGA, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_CARGA, 8) OCT_DATA_CARGA, 
        convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_SAIDA, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_SAIDA, 8) OCT_DATA_SAIDA, 
        convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_CANCELADO, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_CANCELADO, 8) OCT_DATA_CANCELADO, 
        convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_OP, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, OCT_DATA_OP, 8) OCT_DATA_OP, OCT_PERTENCE, O_QTD_CARGA, O_END_COLETA, O_CADENCIA, 
        O_TARIFA, O_DESTINO, O_END_DESTINO, O_PEDIDO_MIC, 
        O_IMPORTACAO, O_DI, O_NAVIO, O_QTD, O_FRETE, 
        convert(varchar, O_DATA_LIBERACAO, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, O_DATA_LIBERACAO, 8) O_DATA_LIBERACAO, 
        convert(varchar, O_DATA_VALIDADE, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, O_DATA_VALIDADE, 8) O_DATA_VALIDADE, 
        convert(varchar, O_DATA_CRIACAO, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, O_DATA_CRIACAO, 8) O_DATA_CRIACAO, O_PORTO, O_JANELA, O_BERCO, O_CARGA_CARREGADA, USU_NOME
        FROM ORDEM_CARREGAMENTO 
        LEFT JOIN ORDEM_CARREGAMENTO_T  ON OCT_ORDEM_ID = O_ID 
        LEFT JOIN USUARIO_LOGIN ON USU_ID = O_TRANSPORTADORA  ".$where." ");
    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
        if($row['O_TIPO'] == 'out'){
            $array_out[] = $row;
        }else if($row['O_TIPO'] == 'in'){
            $array_in[] = $row[]
        }
    }

    foreach($array_out as $out){

        $linha++;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $linha, $out['O_ID']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $linha, $out['O_PEDIDO_PRO']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $linha, $out['O_PEDIDO_CLI']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $linha, $out['O_CLIENTE']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $linha, $out['O_TOTAL_PROG']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, $linha, $out['O_DATA_SOLICITA']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $linha, $out['O_DATA_PROD']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(7, $linha, $out['O_DATA_ENTREGA']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(8, $linha, $out['O_DATA_PREVISAO']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(9, $linha, $array_status_pai[$out['O_STATUS']]);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(10, $linha, $out['USU_NOME']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(11, $linha, $out['OCT_MOTORISTA_NOME']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(12, $linha, $out['OCT_VOLUME']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(13, $linha, $out['OCT_PLACA_CAVALO']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(14, $linha, $out['OCT_PLACA_CARRETA']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(15, $linha, ($out['OCT_STATUS'] != NULL) ? $array_status_filho[$out['OCT_STATUS']] : '');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(16, $linha, $out['OCT_DATA_CHEGADA']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(17, $linha, $out['OCT_DATA_ENTRADA']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(18, $linha, $out['OCT_DATA_CARGA']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(19, $linha, $out['OCT_DATA_SAIDA']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(20, $linha, $out['OCT_DATA_CANCELADO']);
    }

    //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setSharedStyle($sharedStyle1, "A1:U2");

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('J')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('K')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('L')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('M')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('N')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('O')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('P')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('Q')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('R')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('S')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('T')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getColumnDimension('U')->setAutoSize(true);


    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->setTitle('InBound');
    // cabeçalho da planilha
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'InBound.')
            ->setCellValue('A2', 'ID')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'Produto')
            ->setCellValue('C2', 'DI')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'Coleta')
            ->setCellValue('E2', 'Total Programado')
            ->setCellValue('F2', 'Solicitação')
            ->setCellValue('G2', 'Produção')
            ->setCellValue('H2', 'Entrega')
            ->setCellValue('I2', 'Previsão')
            ->setCellValue('J2', 'Status da OC')
            ->setCellValue('K2', 'Transportadora')
            ->setCellValue('L2', 'Motorista')
            ->setCellValue('M2', 'Volume')
            ->setCellValue('N2', 'Placa Cavalo')
            ->setCellValue('O2', 'Placa Carreta')
            ->setCellValue('P2', 'Status')
            ->setCellValue('Q2', 'Chegada')
            ->setCellValue('R2', 'Entrada')
            ->setCellValue('S2', 'Carregamento')
            ->setCellValue('T2', 'Saida')
            ->setCellValue('U2', 'Cancelado');


    }   
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save($_SESSION['ROOT'].'/file/relatorio/logistic/'.$file_name);


    echo trim($file_name);
}
```

Comment: Por que fez isto `a.setAttribute('href',...` e logo em seguida isto `a.href ='<?php echo ...`, não tem porque, o primeiro nem será processado, vc esta sobrescrevendo de qualquer forma. Não temos como saber pq `relatorio.xls` virou `_ __ _ __ _relatorio.xls`, deve ser erro no teu back-end (no teu handle.php), trim não vai resolver isto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ta ai a resolução do problema...

```
a.download = response.trim();
```

Tem que por o trim no retorno do javascript.

Para os ignorantes de plantão, valeu por negativar.